# Conditional rendering on load with AMP-HTML

Tags: rendering, amp-html

I have a JSON file and I'd like to render elements based on the value of a property in JSON file. Let's think the JSON is something like this:

```
{"Items":
   [
      {"Title":"Text","Type" : 1,...},
      {"Title":"Text","Type" : 0,...},
      {"Title":"Text","Type" : 0,...},
      {"Title":"Text","Type" : 1,...},
      {"Title":"Text","Type" : 0,...}
   ]
}
```

in my AMP project, I used something like this:

```
<div [class]="{{type}} == 0 ? 'class-0' : 'class-0' ">DATA</div>
```

but this will **only** work when the state changes, **not** in rendering for first time. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is impossible to evaluate bind expressions on page load. The docs clearly say as follows :

> For performance and to avoid the risk of unexpected content jumping, amp-bind does not evaluate expressions on page load. This means that the visual elements should be given a default state and not rely amp-bind for initial render.

However `amp-access` can perform conditional rendering on page load without user interaction. Depending on your requirement you should be able to achieve this using `amp-access`.